# How to show that $[0,1]^n$ is homeomorphic to $D^n$ and ...

Tags: general-topology

I am struck on a problem in my algebraic topology class, so I am posting it here in the hope of getting some help.

If $D^n$ denote the unit ball , then show that $[0,1]^n$ is homeomorphic to $D^n$. Let $(D^n)^{+} = ${ $ x=(x_1,...,x_n) | x_n \geq 0, x \in D^n $}. Show that $D^n$ is homeomorphic to $(D^n)^{+}$.

The issue I am facing is that I am not able to construct a map in both the cases. Can you please let me know how to construct the map?

Rest of verification I would like to do by myself.

Kindly help.

Comment: Radial projection from the centre (1) and imagine inflating the lower ball to a full ball (2)

Comment: For the first problem, you could also try induction as you even have an equality for the first step with $D^1=[0,1]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$[0,1]^n\cong D^n$:

Let $f(0)=0$ and  $$f(x)=\frac{\|x\|_\infty x}{\|x\|_2}$$ for $x\ne 0$ where $\|x\|_\infty=\max |x_i|$, and $\|x\|_2=\sqrt{\sum x_i^2}$. Then, $\|f(x)\|_2=\|x\|_\infty$ and since the cube $[-1,1]^n$ is also the set $\{x\in \mathbb{R}^n|\|x\|_\infty\le 1\}$ we find that $\|f(x)\|_2\le 1$. The inverse is

$$f^{-1}(x)=\frac{\|x\|_2x}{\|x\|_\infty}$$

for $x\ne 0$ and $f^{-1}(0)=0$. Since $\|f^{-1}(x)\|_\infty=\|x\|_2$, we get that these are bijections between the cube and the ball. Of course, you used the ball $[0,1]^n$ so you need to compose that with a homeomorphism $[0,1]^n\cong [-1,1]^n$.

$D^n\cong (D^n)^+$:

Write $\mathbb{R}^n$ as $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}\times \mathbb{R}$. So, elements are $x=(y,x_n)$ for $y\in \mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ and $x_n\in \mathbb{R}$. Then $x\in D^n\iff\|y\|_2^2+x_n^2\le 1$. Define $g:D^n\to (D^n)^+$ by

$$g:(y,x_n)\mapsto \left(y,\tfrac{x_n+\sqrt{1-\|y\|_2^2}}{2}\right)$$

The point is that $|x_n|\le \sqrt{1-\|y\|_2^2}$, so $x_n+\sqrt{1-\|y\|_2^2}\ge 0$.

$$g^{-1}:(y,x_n)\mapsto \left(y,\tfrac{x_n-\sqrt{1-\|y\|_2^2}}{2}\right)$$

Comment: Do you have any comments for 2nd part also?

Comment: If you're happy that I've answered your question, perhaps you could accept the answer?

Comment: I am very sorry I was very busy!